# Extracting matched child json from a nested JSON object with jq

Tags: json, jq

Given a JSON array of objects thus:

```
 {
  "header" : {
    "user" : "baskar"
  },
  "requests" : [ {
    "first_name" : "mike",
    "last_name" : "mat"
  }, {
    "first_name" : "mike1",
    "last_name" : "mat"
  } ],
  "check" : [ "Y" ]
}
```

I'd like to extract a subset of the key/values from the nested requests based on the condition, whilst keeping other properties from the outer object intact, producing something like:  When i search for first_name='mike'

```
{
  "header" : {
    "user" : "baskar"
  },
  "requests" : [ {
    "first_name" : "mike",
    "last_name" : "mat"
  } ],
  "check" : [ "Y" ]
}
```

I tried the below thing,

```
[.requests[] | select(.first_name == "mike")]
```

But, it gives the subset of the matched requests but not returning header and check element.

I'm sure there must be a reasonably easy way of achieving this with jq. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think of it in terms of updating the requests array by filtering it.

This should work:

```
.requests |= map(select(.first_name == "mike"))
```

Comment: Awesome it works if it is wrapped inside a bracket. But my actual request does not have bracket. I have edited my requests. The above command does not work with the above request.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. .requests |= map(select(.first_name == "mike")). this works in this case.